# Entendiendo la colas o tareas

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

He terminado la parte de una aplicacion dedicada a los backups.
Ahora cuando trato de implementarla usando la colas y tareas de laravel 5.3, me siento incapaz.

Tengo una suerte de comandos

```
cpr:backups {full|acct} {full|account} {daily|weekly|monthly}
cpr:backup {account|system} {full|account} {daily|weekly|monthly}
```

El primero cpr:backups puede generar (o debe generar porque ya me he perdido) o una tarea o tantas tareas como usuarios hay en el sistema independientes, que deberian ser "encoladas" para ser ejecutadas despues.

en el cron

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

En el fichero que controla los backups

```
...
foreach ($users as $user)
{
   // $type puede ser daily|weekly|monthly
   $job = new MakeBackups($user->id,$model);
   dispatch($job);
}
```

En el fichero app\Jobs\MakeBackups.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Log;

class MakeBackups implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $userId;
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId,$model)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Do something 
        Log::info('Make a backups for user with id '.$this->userId.' within the User class');
    }
```

Cuando verifico, efectivamente se han añadido a la tabla jobs, un trabajo por cada uno de los usuarios

```
queue -> default
payload -> {"job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\MakeBackups","command":"O:20:\"App\\Jobs\\MakeBackups\":5:{s:9:\"\u0000*\u0000userId\";s:1:\"1\";s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;}"}}
```

Pero si intento ejecutar manualmente la cola.

```
artisan schedule:run 
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

A estas alturas, entiendo que no he comrpendido el funcionamiento basico de las tasks o las colas, en diferido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás confundiendo o mezclando dos conceptos que pueden estar relacionados, pero que son distintos, al menos en Laravel.

Las [**Queues**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) o "colas" son trabajos que se ejecutan en segundo plano, uno tras otro, organizados y con el fin de no recargar el servidor, los cuales se ejecutarán cuando el servidor "pueda" hacerlo, bien sea 1 segundo o 1 hora después de haber sido agregados a la fila, cola o queue. Podrías apoyarte en `php artisan queue:work` para ejecutar los trabajos agregados a la fila lo más pronto posible, según lo que necesites hacer en tu aplicación en un momento determinado.

Procesar el registro de un usuario (dependiendo las etapas que tengas) puede ser agregado a la cola, realizar el envio de un correo de verificación o un recordatorio, o generar/almacenar determinada información que puede tardar mucho tiempo o consumir muchos recursos (y si no deseamos que ocurran 10 de estos procesos al tiempo), son ejemplos de trabajos que se pueden agregar a la cola y que no necesitan ser ejecutados de inmediato.

[**Task scheduling**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) sirve para programar tareas y que se ejecuten en un momento o con una frecuencia determinada. Para ejecutar dichas tareas es que utilizar el comando `schedule run`, preferiblemente en el cron: `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Hacer un backup de determinado contenido a X hora exacta puede ser vital para la aplicación, enviar el newsletter diario/semanal, limpiar almacenamiento de logs, indexar, son algunos ejemplos de tareas que debamos ejecutar con cierta frecuencia a un momento determinado, y "debe" ser en ese momento.

---

**¿Cómo podrían relacionarse los dos conceptos?**

Una tarea programada (que se ejecutará con `schedule run`) puede agregar trabajos a la cola o queue, por ejemplo el envío del newsletter debe realizarse a la medianoche, pero supongamos que no es vital que todos los usuarios lo reciban a esa hora, entonces podemos agregar el trabajo a la fila por partes y será ejecutado "cuando el servidor pueda o cuando tu aplicación lo exija/permita".

El mismo ejemplo se puede aplicar a tus backups: Podrías programar la tarea de agregarlos a la cola en una hora determinada del día.

Lo contrario también es posible: Cuando ejecutes un trabajo que agregaste a la cola o queue, este va a agregar/generar una tarea programada que deberá ejecutarse a determinada hora.

Comment: Gracias. Ayer realizando pruebas entendi mas o menos el concepto. Lo unico que no veo claro, es que si agrego trabajos a   las colas, y estos trabajos toman mas de 1 minuto, y tengo un cron cada minuto, para procesar que queue:work, si el primer trabajo de la cola se esta procesando, el segundo se iniciara o el propio mecanismo de laravel dejara el trabajo para la siguiente comprobacion. GRacias,.